# Does anyone know where I can get the entire list of all Unicode code points?

Tags: unicode

I don't know why i might need it but I wanted to look up all the Unicode data points because I wanted to find all the cool things in there apart form Emoji. So does anyone know where I can get the table. The official one is only useful if you know the data point to find what it does, but I want it the other way round. I cant find anything more than the Wikipedia HTML version and one from UTF-1.

Comment: Have you taken a look [here](http://unicode.org)?

Comment: Does https://codepoints.net/ cover what you're looking for? Also have a look at https://github.com/Codepoints/awesome-codepoints for "cool things" :)

Comment: [http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)